# Matlab plot title won't show

Tags: matlab, plot

Here is a very simple MWE :

```
figure
x = 1:10;
plot(x)
title('mytitle','interpreter','none')
```

And the result with no title showing :
[image]

I am under Windows 7, Matlab R2015a. I do want the interpreter to be set to 'none' because I will be working with titles containing consecutive underscores - which would fail in Latex. And when I open the figure properties dialog and double-click on the title, it appears and is editable. Once I unselect it though, it disappears again. Help...

Comment: Why open the figure properties dialog? Also can't reproduce on OS X

Comment: I opened the figure properties dialog to check whether the title would appear in it. And if I do Insert > Title, the title "mytitle" pops up and I can edit it. But once I unselect it, by clicking anywhere on the graph, it disappears again. As if it was sent to the background of everything.

Comment: To add some info : if I set the interpreter to 'latex', the title shows up properly (as long as it respects latex syntax). Unfortunately, I am working with someone else's code at the moment and cannot change variable names so they respect latex syntax.

Comment: That seems like a strange bug. You could always replace all `_` with `\textunderscore`: `title(strrep('my__title', '_', '\textunderscore '), 'interpreter', 'latex')`

Comment: Unfortunately again, I am working with Dynare, a Matlab package that has its own graphical output routines. Thus I don't even have access to the title(...) commands you suggested to fix. I sort of have a way around for now but it's not optimal and makes me waste some time everytime I need to update the graphs and look at them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wait so what is the `title` that you used in your initial post? Is that an overloaded function? If so, it's not really a MWE.

Comment: No, in the MWE it's the original Matlab function. At first, I indeed thought the bug was linked to the package I am using, but it's not.

Comment: Got it! By default, Matlab used the Helvetica font, which is not available on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that Matlab's default font was Helvetica, which is not available on my computer. So make sure to use a font available on your computer, by using the `FontName` argument if needed.

You can also set the default text font (here Courier) through :

```
set(0,'defaultTextFontName','Courier')
```